ntsc -> modern video interfaces
What is a recommended way nowadays to add a more modern video output options to a (fpga based) project that outputs ntsc signal?  Getting ntsc output right is important for me. Having any of the other interfaces is just a matter of convenience.

The project does not seem retro, you seem to want a modern video output in a modern FPGA project that already has a NTSC color composite video output. Can you please clarify?

NTSC output ?

it's a 8bit home computer with ntsc output. I can't rely on ntsc compatible displays being readily available in the future, can I?

@Anton But it's unclear if you want to simply take in an analog NTSC video output of an existing device into your device and convert it to digital, or do you want your modern FPGA to output analog NTSC and modern digital interface at the same time? Neither is however retro, it's making a modern new device.

To ve honest - I don't care. I sure want to output analog NTSC - for me it's a proof that a project works. How exactly the other signals are generated is not important(and what interfaces are implemented is negotiable) - I just don't expect NTSC hardware to be readily available in the future. May be I'm wrong and NTSC decoders will always be available in TVs - that would be an ideal solution.

@Anton OK, but since the video is anyway generated and output by an FPGA, it is digital. It needs to go digitally to DAC or video encoder IC and out comes NTSC analog color video. You can do the same for any other interface, with slight adaptations, but the digital video would go to another IC that would output DVI or generate it inside FPGA. But none of that is retro.

To clarify the question: you have an existing device (an FPGA-based 8-bit home computer) that has an NTSC color composite video output, and you want some way to view that output on modern (current and foreseeable future) screens — yes?  If so: 1) Can you modify the device, or must this be a separate device connected to its NTSC output?  And 2) Why do you say that analog NTSC must be proof that it works, when a more modern format would clearly be a better proof?  (NTSC has never been universal — not in much of the non-American parts of the world, anyway!)

"existing device"
In progress, I'm trying to debug it:)
"has an NTSC color composite video output"
Yes
"Can you modify the device"
Yes, but I'm an absolute novice so I'm looking for the easiest way possible
"Why do you say that analog NTSC must be proof that it works"
Well, it's a game of "we're in 1980, what if...". Most likely such a device would appear in USA, hence NTSC, not PAL. Getting NTSC output was a requirement, going an all-digital route would be cheating.

@Anton but how does it make the digital and convert it to NTSC composite now, does it use a video encoder chip, resistor network DAC for analog RGB or YUV and a color modulator chip? You are being very secretive and not answering the questions that would help to decide how to answer the question you asked. Schematics would help too which would answer most questions even without asking them.

Resister ladder. Sorry, there are no secrets, it's an old tech after all, I just don't know what's important.

Analog TV to digital converters (and vice versa) are readily available.

@Anton You are succesfully generating video source material, encoding it as colour composite NTSC signal digitally inside FPGA and outputing it to a R2R ladder DAC for analog output? But can't output the same generated source material for any other device like a DVI encoder chip? They are basically the same thing.
